# C# Picture Box Loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written loop for picture box, it looks like this:

```
void labelAdder()
{
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    List<TextBox> texboxex = new List<TextBox>();
    List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length - 1; i++)
    {   
        equals++;
        var temp = new TextBox();
        var temp2 = new PictureBox();

        int x = 10; 
        int y = xD * equals;

        temp.Location = new Point(x, y); 
        temp2.Location = new Point(x + 100, y); 
        temp2.Image = global::Xbox360_Complex_Checker.Properties.Resources.button_offline;

        temp.Text = args[i];
        temp2.Text = status[i];

        this.Controls.Add(temp);
        this.Controls.Add(temp2);

        temp.Show();
        temp2.Show();

        texboxex.Add(temp);
        pictureBoxes.Add(temp2);
    }   
}
```

My problem is that `PictureBox` is loading only next to first `textBox`, it should load next to all textBoxes. I don't know why it's not working. I tried this with labels, and labels were loading properly.

Comment: Welcome! Is this WinForms? If so, you should tag it so experts in the appropriate UI technology will be drawn to your question.

Comment: You should be using composite or UserControls for things like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.100).aspx It would save you a lot of issues trying to associate separate controls on a form.

Comment: Any examples with pictureBox are available? :|

Comment: Can't repro it.  Your `xD` variable is undocumented.  Also, consider using better variable names.  `temp` and `temp2` don't help the coder understand what they are working with.  As mentioned, a UserControl with a PictureBox and a TextBox would make it easier, along with using a FlowLayoutPanel, then you wouldn't need this placement logic.